# How to include image in Vue Component CSS inline styles in a none relative path?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

So I have this Component code

```
<template>
  <div class="example-class">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
  .example-class {
     background-image: url("HOW to include the image here?");
  }
</style>
```

How can I include the image in that style section code?

My component is in a directory

```
src/component/sample-comp/MyComponent.vue
```

My images are in a directory

```
assets/images
```

I already tried using `@/assets/images/sample-image.png` It wont include the image. It is giving an error below

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                      08:53:42
This relative module was not found:

    * ./@/assets/images/cta-bg.png in ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-18a303e8","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/frontend/landing-layouts/CallToAction.vue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the `@` alias as Webpack cannot understand this alias inside the `<style></style>` tags.

There are two options to do this.

---

**First option:**

Since `@` is mapped as `src/` in Webpack, using your component, your path should be `background-image: url('../../assets/images/cta-bg.png')` in the `<style></style>` tags.

---

**Second option:**

You can use the `style` binding directly in the `<div>` tag.

```
<div :style="backgroundImage: `url(${require(`@/assets/images/cta-bg.png`)})`">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just update the background URL form

```
    <template>
  <div class="example-class">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
  .example-class {
     background-image: url("HOW to include the image here?");
  }
</style>
```

To

```
<template>
  <div class="example-class">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
  .example-class {
     background-image: url("~@/assets/images/sidebar.svg");
  }
</style>
```